# Check for active Downloads C#

Tags: c#, download, tcplistener

I am just learning C# and want to write a Shutdown timer Program for Windows.
I already finnished calling the shutdown.exe with arguments but couldn't figure out how to implement a "Shutdown once all Downloads finished"-function.

I want my program to check for active Downloads e.g. in Firefox and delay shutdown until all of them are finished.

Something like:

```
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (downloadsactive == false)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(System.Environment.SystemDirectory + "\\shutdown.exe", "-s -t 10");
        }

    }
```

I googled for like 2 hours now and found nothing useful.

Comment: Chances are, there is no such _system-wide_ flag that indicates whether any download is still active.

Comment: Is it possible to check if a specific program has an active download then?
Like for example firefox.exe? I can get processes by name. But do they have something like a "download"-flag?

Comment: No, only the process itself knows that (by keeping track of the download queue), and usually this information is not exposed to other processes. I think Even the _OS_ cannot tell if a specific process is downloading a file, or just chatting with a server, since the underlying APIs are the same.

Comment: Thanks for your help, kennyzx. I'll try the quick and dirty way via monitoring the Networktraffic itself then.